# Jenkins + No such property: npm for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, npm-install, jenkins-groovy

I have below code in jenkins pipeline

```
  stage("Install Dependencies") {
    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "test.npmrepo.readonly", targetLocation: "${WORKSPACE}/.npmrepo")]){}
     withEnv(["HOME=."]){
      script {
        sh “npm ci”
        sh "git checkout -- .npmrepo"
      }
    }   }
```

I am getting error as shown in screenshot, I guess issue is at "npm ci", kindly advise

Error in Jenkin Console:

[image]

Comment: please share the whole Jenkinsfile, the issue not comes from above code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You have smart quotes in the line sh `“npm ci”`.  Replace them with straight quotes.